# Eclipse RCP product - is there anyway to update the PATH during launch

Tags: eclipse, path, rcp

I am working on an eclipse RCP product on windows which internally uses some native binaries (dlls) located in a folder called "bin" which would be available as a part of the product.
I need to make sure that the folder "bin" is present in the PATH when the product.exe file is executed. Is there a clean way to make sure that the folder "bin" is added to PATH when the eclipse RCP product is launched?
I don't want to write any script or batch file that updates the PATH and then calls the product.exe. I also don't want to update the environment variable through the windows UI or command prompt.

I know that when we try to run my product from the eclipse IDE environment, there is an option in the run-configuration, wherein one can configure Environment variables on the Environment tab. I can append the "bin" folder to the PATH by creating a new environment variable called "Path" whose value is C:\EclipseRCPProduct\bin;${env_var:PATH}.

However - I would like to do the same when I run my product directly from the Product.exe which is generated. Does anyone have any idea regarding this?

Also - if anyone has any idea regarding the eclipse code which processes the information specified on the Environment tab of the run configuration, it would be great. I could try playing around with the code to see if I could get it to work when the product is launched from outside eclipse IDE - via the generated RCP product.exe

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's a way to define **system environment variables** within the launcher.

The following bug seems to request just that
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=286463

In the above mentioned bug, a .bat is attached to achieve your goal.

That said, why do the native binaries have to be located in a bin folder?
I.e. why are they not included in a plugin/fragment?